# How to convert a string to a user discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to convert a string to a user so I can dm them. Here's my current code:

```
    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def partnerwarn(ctx):
file_names = glob.glob("p*")
for file in file_names:
    f = open(file, 'r')
    content = f.read()
    f.close()
    member = file[1:]      
    await bot.send_message(member : discord.User, "You've had under 7 partners! This is a warning, please make sure you actively partner!")
    print("Warned!")
    await bot.reply("**" + file[1:] + " was warned!**")
```

It doesn't work because `member : discord.User` is invalid syntax where it currently is. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

When the `command` decorator sees an annotation on one of the arguments to the decorated coroutine, it knows to either use the correct [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) or directly apply the annotation as a callable before the argument is passed to the underlying coroutine.

You can create your own [`MemberConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter) objects and use them to convert strings to `Member`s by using their `convert` coroutines:

```
from discord.ext.commands import MemberConverter

...

converter = MemberConverter()
member = await converter.convert(ctx, file[1:])
```