# discord.py Mention user by name

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to mention a user by their name in discord.py. My current code is:

```
@bot.command(name='mention')
@commands.has_role(OwnerCommands)
async def mention(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
    memberid = member.id
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send('<@{}>'.format(memberid))
```

But it does not work. How do I do this?

Edit, I found an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found a way. I simply turned on Privileged indents in the Discord Developers page.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather straight forward [`member.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=mention#discord.User.mention)

```py
@bot.command(name='mention')
@commands.has_role(OwnerCommands)
async def mention(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(member.mention)
```

Comment: Yeah, but I dont want to have to mention the user in the command. Then, they will get double pinged. I just want to do ?mention ENORMOUZ

Comment: You can use NAME#NUMBER like `AZ#0573`. That would work

Answer (score 0):

We can skip the manual work and use discord's [Member Model](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) directly. The `mention` on the Member object returns us the string to allow us to mention them directly.

```
@bot.command(name='mention')
@commands.has_role(OwnerCommands)
async def mention(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(member.mention)
```

Comment: Yeah, but I dont want to have to mention the user in the command. Then, they will get double pinged. I just want to do ?mention ENORMOUZ

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you don't want to mention the member twice by using discord.py **MemberConverter** extension, And also don't forget to activate the members privileged indents from the discord developer portal.

resources:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter
[How to convert a string to a user discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55270496/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-user-discord-py)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import MemberConverter 

intents = discord.Intents(members = True)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents)

@client.command()
async def mention(ctx, member):
  converter = MemberConverter()
  member = await converter.convert(ctx, (member))
  await ctx.send(member.mention)
```